# Can the PickAndStore method recognize {multiple:false}?

Tags: filepicker.io

Can the PickAndStore method recognize {multiple:false}? Currently is just looks for multiple which means it is harder to dynamically set it.

Comment: what do you mean by 'dynamically set it'?

Comment: foo = false; picker_options {  multiple: foo };

Comment: @Annabel foo = false; picker_options {  multiple: foo };

Comment: Maybe the `multiple: false` setting doesn't work. The only insight I can give is that I just had to change my code to go from having separate `pick` and `store` calls to one `pickAndStore' and then I found that `FPFile` passed to the `OnSuccess` function changed from being a single `FPFile` object to an array of them (with just one element). Maybe there's something a bit ilogical about the code.

Comment: I just tried it out on a test page and `multiple: false` does work. Also just leaving out the `multiple` altogether also works.

Comment: hmm, i'll test again. I have my code setup to just leave out multiple if it is false. But I tested and found that if multiple was present it would allow it event if it was false. maybe I had a truthy false? I'll check my code.